# Pass parameters on community login URL

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-lightning

I want my login URL to be appended with some params. In the community login controller class I want to retrieve this URL value and create a record based on that. I tried to set those params as an attribute and on the init method I tried to fetch those attributes but it does not work. Can somebody post me some sample code to get the values of params in the URL.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you're using to try to do this? That will make it easier for people to formulate an appropriate answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm

i.e.

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParamName');
```

Comment: I want to do the same in the lightning component.

Comment: lightning is funny with url parameters and urls in general since it tries to be a single page app framework, but on a quick glance have you looked at this https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000g1blIAA ?

Comment: Yes that link helped. Thanks